# Three div make the layout

Tags: html, css

I've tried to implement the following multiple different way, but haven't been able to get it to display correctly. There's only three divs, no positioning, no margins -- I'm just using float. Can someone please let me know how I can achieve this?

[image]

Comment: more info. is needed. does any of these `div` has a fixed with?

Answer (score 0):

This should work with floats well

**HTML**

```
<div class="redbox"></div>
<div class="dother2box">
    <div class="orangebox"></div>
    <div class="greenbox"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.redbox {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
.dother2box {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.orangebox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: orange;
}
.greenbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: green;
}
```

Hope this works for you